# japanese fonts in firefox ok but from apache no

Tags: apache-httpd, locale

This is my first round with Apache so please forgive my ignorance of principles that any decent Apache administrator should know.

> Apache 2.4.58-1
> 6.6.1-arch1-1
> Mozilla Firefox 119.0.1

I have an email containing Japanese characters that I want to add to a webpage.

The Japanese characters come to me through gmail that in the firefox display of gmail look like Japanese characters. (I don't read Japanese but I can see the difference between neat  Japanese and random garbage characters.)

I paste the characters from the gmail into the HTML file, using VI. They look Japanese, I can  `cat` the HTML file and the characters look Japanese, but when Apache serves up that page it displays random garbage characters.

Summary: On that same machine I can see Japanese characters in Gmail and in the file on disk, but Apache is not serving them up.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/a/868310/229499 ... Assuming your Japanese text has indeed UTF-8 encoded

Comment: Apache has little knowledge of encodings. So you should check the original file (which encoding it has) and in the browser, using the build-in developer tools, check what encoding is used by the browser. Note: Japanese is special: UTF-8 is not so much used

Answer (score 0):

After comments by muru and giacomo-catenazzi I have added to the HTML the following:

```
 <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
 </head>
```

This has fixed the problem.